# Select dependiente guarda id, pero necesito guardar la variable

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```
<code><!-- desde aca empieza select dependiente -->
       <?php
        include('db-config.php');
     $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM provincias ORDER BY provincia ASC");
        $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
       ?>
       <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>
        </span>
       <select name="us_provincia" id="provincia" 
           value="<?php echo $usprovincia; ?>">
       <option value="">Seleccione Provincia</option>

       <?php
         if($rowCount > 0){
           while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
   echo '<optionvalue="'.$row['id_prov'].'">'.$row['provincia'].'</option>';
           }
         }else{
        echo '<option value=""> no disponible</option>';
         }
        ?>
         </select>
         </div>

         <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i></span>
       <select name="us_ciudad" id="ciudad" value="<?php echo $usciudad; >">
          <option value="">ciudad</option>
       </select>
        </div>

        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#provincia').on('change',function(){
         var provinciaID =$(this).val();
          if(provinciaID){
         $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url:'ajaxData.php',
         data:'id_prov='+provinciaID,

         success:function(html){
         $('#ciudad').html(html);
          }
           });
            }else{
          $('#ciudad').html('<option value="">Ciudad</option>');
             }
           });
          });
        </script>

        <!-- aca termina select dependiente -->
</code>
```

Entiendo que me guarda el id solamente porque es lo que estoy haciendo, pero quisiera una idea de como poder guardar los nombres de las variables, no su id.

Y la pagina ajaxData.php :

```
<code>
    <?php
     include('db-config.php');
      if(isset($_POST["id_prov"]) && !empty($_POST["id_prov"])){
       $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ciudades
         WHERE id_prov =".$_POST['id_prov']." ORDER BY ciudad ASC");
           $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
       if($rowCount > 0){
         echo '<option value="">Seleccione ciudad</option>';
       while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
         echo '<option
      value="'.$row['id_ciudad'].'">'.$row['ciudad'].'</option>';
       }
        }else{
           echo '<option value="">no disponible</option>';
        }
      }
    ?>
</code>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Mientras más claro seas planteando la pregunta la ayuda llegará más rápido. También, es de mal gusto que lo primero que sueltes en una pregunta sea un montón de código sin explicar absolutamente nada. Por ejemplo aquí: *Entiendo que me guarda **el id** solamente porque es lo que estoy haciendo, pero quisiera una idea de como poder guardar los nombres de **las variables**, no su id.*  hablas como si estuviéramos en tu mente, como si supiéramos **cuál es el id y cuáles son las variables**... no lo sabemos, ¿por qué tenemos que buscarlo en el código?

Comment: ¿Guardar donde? ¿Guardar que? .... no se entiende nada.

Comment: **negrita** Hola JDev, intenté ser claro en mi pregunta y quizás no fui eficiente, mostré el código que tengo que claramente se entiende que es un select dependiente y aclaro que entiendo me guarda solamente el id de la variable que recibe para que no me estén aclarando tal cosa, y pido ayuda claramente en como poder hacer para guardar el texto que recibo y no el id.  Trato de no ser "pesado" en las preguntas pero se ve que todavía no aprendo, lo que te pediría si podrías darme un ejemplo de como hubieses formulado tu esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder al texto de la variable seleccionada desde el onchange como se muestra en el ejemplo. Una vez almacenado lo puedes enviar como parte de los datos del `ajax` al igual que el id.

```js
$('#provincia').on('change',function(){
 var provinciaID =$(this).val();
 var provinciaText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
//.....
 alert(provinciaID + "---" + provinciaText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="provincia">
 <option value="1">Texto1</option>
 <option value="2">Texto2</option>
 <option value="3">Texto3</option>
</select>
```